# C# script to clean file takes a long time to execute

Tags: c#, .net, ssis, text-files

I have this script ; which takes a long time to run even though files are 0.4 GB. There are 1000+ file and each time I execute this script it take roughly 1 minute  for each file.

Is there any way I can speed up this script ?

```
 String strFile = File.ReadAllText(
    Dts.Variables["User::File_Name_Path_4"].Value.ToString());
 strFile = strFile.Replace("#Fields: ", "");

 File.WriteAllText(
    Dts.Variables["User::File_Name_Path_4"].Value.ToString(), strFile);
```

Comment: Did you use profiling to determine exactly where the time is spent?

Comment: I think the problem will be the `Replace` operation, when the slurped text gets bigger it might take longer. But this depends on it's implementation.

Comment: Maybe you could process the file line by line, instead of slurping it all at once. Or process it in other chunks, whatever might be appropriate for your solution.

Comment: How much of the fcl have you got at disposal in this script? That is do you only have a subset.  You could get asynchronous and parallel approach going here.

Comment: Are you running Visual Studio with Analyze menu option at the top? It might be worth it just to see what percentage time is spent between the read, replace and write parts. If you don't have those tools, try to comment out only the Replace line to prove 100% that the majority of the delay is caused there.

Comment: @brumScouse yes if the CPU processing rather than IO is the bottleneck here a Parallel for loop can make a huge different, each taking on a file at a time perhaps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the files are large (> a few KB), reading the whole thing into memory is a bad idea. It creates a lot of work for the allocator and the collector. A better idea is to stream the contents from one place to another and do the replace on each piece. This sample assumes that lines aren't too big. If file is on a single line you would have to do something more sophisticated to read in smaller chunks (and make sure you didn't happen to break the text on what you are trying to replace).

```
string tempFile = Path.GetTempFileName();
string fileName = Dts.Variables["User::File_Name_Path_4"].Value.ToString();
using (var writer = new StreamWriter(tempFile))
using (var reader = new StreamReader(fileName))
{
    while(!reader.EndOfStream)
    {
        writer.WriteLine(reader.ReadLine().Replace("#Fields: ", ""));
    }
}
File.Delete(fileName);
File.Move(tempFile, fileName);
```